# Difference between Scatter object and figure.scatter method

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, interactive

I have the following question related to these two graphs:

**Graph 1:**

```
output_notebook()
scatter = Scatter(df_b, x='log_umsatz', y='log_fte', color='target', legend="top_right")
show(scatter)
```

[image]

**Graph 2**

```
output_notebook()
scatter = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500)
scatter.scatter(x=df_b['log_umsatz'], y=df_b['log_fte'], color=df['target'])
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
show(scatter)
```

[image]

As you can see, I generated two scatter graphs using bokeh. In the second graph, I try to introduce some interactivity with `p.legend.click_policy="hide"`. I have two issues: The interactivity doesn't work, and legend and color coding are lost in the second example. How come? I expected graph 1 and graph 2 to be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are using for Graph 1 `Scatter` which is a Bokeh Charts model. Bokeh Charts is a high level library for plotting data and does a lot of data processing and chart formatting for you behind the scenes. In Graph 2, you are using a Bokeh glyph to create your plot and so you need to be much more explicit in what you want it to do.

Fixing up your code I can produce the same graph as that original Scatter.

```
cds = ColumnDataSource(df_b)
color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(
    palette=['red', 'green'], factors=[0, 1])

scatter = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500)
scatter.circle(x='log_umsatz', y='log_fte',
               color={'field': 'target', 'transform': color_mapper}, alpha=0.5,
               source=cds, legend='target')
scatter.legend.location = "top_right"
```

As you can see, we need to call in multiple other Bokeh objects. `ColumnDataSource` to store the pandas data and `CategoricalColorMapper` to map the colors to the factors.

---

Now adding an interactive legend to the plot is a little more complicated. Right now on Bokeh interactive legend works on a per glyph basis. That is to say each glyph must be plotted separately to be intractable. You can read more about it [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.5/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html), and here's a quick demo to help you.

```
scatter = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500)
scatter.circle(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], color='red', legend='0', alpha=0.5)
scatter.circle(x=[4, 5], y=[4, 5], color='green', legend='1', alpha=0.5)
scatter.legend.location = "top_right"
scatter.legend.click_policy = "hide"
```